# Not understanding how to make my for loop and if statement work

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

I have this, but I'm very lost in how I can get the final GPA to print out, I've tried various ways but have not been able to do it successfully. This is what I have:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many grades are you putting? ");
    int length = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();

    String[] gradesArray = new String[length];

    for(int i = 0; i < gradesArray.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter grade (include + or -) ");
        gradesArray[i] = input.nextLine();

        double points = 0.0;
        if(gradesArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("A+") || gradesArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
        {
           points += 4;

        }
        else if(gradesArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("A-"))
        {
            points+= 3.7;

        }
        else if(gradesArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("B+"))
        {
            points += 3.3;

        }
        else if(gradesArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("B"))
        {
            points += 3.0;

        }
        else if(gradesArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("B-"))
        {
            points += 2.7;

        }
        else if(gradesArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("C+"))
        {
            points += 2.3;

        }
        else if(gradesArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
        {
            points += 2.0;

        }
        else if(gradesArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("D"))
        {
            points += 1.0;

        }
        else if(gradesArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("F"))
        {
            points += 0.0;

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid grade");
        }
        System.out.println("GPA: " + points / gradesArray.length);
    }
```

I'm guessing the GPA does not print out properly because after the condition matches the grade, it then goes right down to print, right? And also, how can I do it so if they enter an invalid grade, it makes the user start over.

Comment: Unrelated to the answer, but you might want to have a look at this instead of having a bunch of else if statements: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: Why are you printing GPA inside the loop?

Comment: Thanks, I'll make a separate class to see how this works. I totally forgot about switch; mostly because I only used it once in AP Computer Science. If I print out GPA outside the loop, then the points variable is no longer in the scope and nothing happens

Comment: Functionally a case statement is basically the equivalent (provided you use breaks as needed), it's really more of a readability thing more than anything else.

Answer (score 2):

You're very close. You need to add another bracket before your `println` to close out your `forloop`. You only want to calculate GPA once **all** of the grades are entered. So like this:

And, as Jason mentioned in the comments, you need to make sure to create `points` outside of the loop. Otherwise, you won't be able to access it afterwards to get calculate the full GPA.

```
double points = 0.0;  //this has to go out here to be able to access it later

for(int i = 0; i < gradesArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter grade (include + or -) ");
    gradesArray[i] = input.nextLine();

    ...

    else if(gradesArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("F")) {
        points += 0.0;

    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid grade");
    }
}
System.out.println("GPA: " + points / gradesArray.length);
```

As for resetting input, this is easy as well. You can just use a `while` loop - so do something like this.

```
boolean inputNeeded = true;

while(inputNeeded) {
    System.out.println("Please enter grades:);
    String grade = scan.nextLine();
    if(grade_is_valid_check_here) {
        inputNeeded = false;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Input is invalid - please try again");
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `double points = 0.0;` be declared outside of the loop since it's a total of all of the points and you don't want it reset through every loop iteration?

Comment: @JasonRoman wow I didn't even catch that. Thanks - I'll fix that and mention it in the answer

Answer (score 1):

You could do something similar to this as well. You can use a switch block. `points` needs to be brought outside the loop or it will just get reset to 0.0 every time a user enters a grade.

To make the user start over if it is an invalid grade you could use a recursive call. This means after the the "Invalid grade" message you would call the method that starts the process over again. This would require a little more refactoring and separating some of this code into more methods.

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double points = 0.0;

    System.out.println("How many grades are you putting? ");
    int length = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();

    String[] gradesArray = new String[length];

    for(int i = 0; i < gradesArray.length; i++){
        System.out.println("Enter grade (include + or -) ");
        gradesArray[i] = input.nextLine();

        String grade = gradesArray[i].toUpperCase();
        switch (gradesArray[i]) {
            case "A+":
                points += 4;
                break;
            case "A":
                points += 4;
                break;
            case "A-":
                points += 3.7;
                break;
            case "B+":
                points += 3.3;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid grade");
                break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("GPA: " + points / gradesArray.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from @Alex K's answer. Not sure if you have learned about `HashMaps` or not, but you could shorten your code down quite a bit by using them. It also makes it way easier to add another grade and point value with ease.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );

System.out.println("How many grades are you putting? ");
int length = input.nextInt();

String[] gradesArray = new String[length];
//Create a HashMap with String as the key, and a Double as the value
Map < String, Double > grades = new HashMap < > ();
//Insert all the grades and point values
grades.put("A+", 4.0);
grades.put("A-", 3.7);
grades.put("B+", 3.3);
grades.put("B", 3.0);
grades.put("B-", 2.7);
grades.put("C+", 2.3);
grades.put("C", 2.0);
grades.put("D", 1.0);
grades.put("F", 0.0);

double points = 0.0;

for (int i = 0; i < gradesArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter grade (include + or -) ");
    String grade = input.nextLine();
    gradesArray[i] = grade;
    //If the grades Map contains the inputted grade, use Map.get(grade) to obtain the value and add that to the points Double. 
    //Otherwise print invalid grade
    if (grades.containsKey(grade)) {
        points += grades.get(gradesArray[i]);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid grade");
    }
}
System.out.println("GPA: " + points / gradesArray.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is declare points as a global variable and print out the GPA outside the for loop

```
 public class Grade {

public static void main(String[] args){
double points=0.0;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("How many grades are you putting? ");
int length = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();

String[] gradesArray = new String[length];

for(int i = 0; i < gradesArray.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Enter grade (include + or -) ");
    gradesArray[i] = input.nextLine();


    if(gradesArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("A+") || gradesArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
    {
       points += 4;

    }
    else if(gradesArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("A-"))
    {
        points+= 3.7;

    }
    else if(gradesArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("B+"))
    {
        points += 3.3;

    }
    else if(gradesArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("B"))
    {
        points += 3.0;

    }
    else if(gradesArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("B-"))
    {
        points += 2.7;

    }
    else if(gradesArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("C+"))
    {
        points += 2.3;

    }
    else if(gradesArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
    {
        points += 2.0;

    }
    else if(gradesArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("D"))
    {
        points += 1.0;

    }
    else if(gradesArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("F"))
    {
        points += 0.0;

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid grade");
    }
}
    System.out.println("GPA: " + points / gradesArray.length);
}
```